# What does “boots” mean in this context about making technological improvement and making work easier?

Tags: meaning, technology

I encountered this usage:

> We can do massive training closer to the operator on a smartphone, using their own device, right now, we’re doing tests in plants, so people have **boots** and computers and they can test themselves.

Here, they are talking about technological improvements that could help making work easier.

I only find one meaning of **boot** in dictionaries regarding the technological context: *The process of starting a computer and putting it into a state of readiness for operation* (Oxford Dictionary). However, I think that this meaning is not referred to this context.

Do you know any other meaning of **boots** that could fit this context?

Some context of the source text, this is what the member says right before:

> Last year, I told you about the digital learning lab we had created, the platform and that we started 30 online training modules that were accessible on computers, in English only, for M&Ps. This year, we have something accessible to everybody with an email account, around 45 000 people and this is growing daily.
>
> This year we have about 130 digital trainings, we hope to include operators next year. We are now moving to other languages than English, though most of those in the Group and trainings are now available on iPad, computers, iPhones, without a password, people can train themselves on their mobiles.
>
> I believe we now have an infrastructure that gives full access to 45 000 people, the goal for 2019 is for everybody to have access.
>
> We are really ahead of the competition, we are really pushing the game ahead in terms of massive access.

Comment: Please give more context. Particularly good would be a link.

Comment: So there is no web source? The capitalisation of "Group" and use of "trainings" suggests a non-native English speaker, so possibly 'boots' is a mistranslation from a word in another language, or maybe a typo (books?) . There is no obvious meaning for 'boots' in that context.

Comment: This can't be right. **Where do your quotes come from?** *Trainings,* for example, is so non-standard as to be wrong.

Comment: You might want to Google "boots on the ground".

Comment: Possibly a typo for "books"? That's the only thing I can think of that could fit. Or a mistranslation of pad/tablet? It isn't clear where this text is from - can you not ask **them** what they mean? It is clearly an error of some kind.

Comment: ***tests in plants*** =tests in factories? so you would need boots to be safe. I guess my particular profession makes stuff jump out at me. But yes, trainings with an s is totally grrrh. :) That said: operator on a smartphone sounds weird. And "member" of  what exactly?

Comment: And now I am wondering what the M&Ps are in the 2nd extract...

Comment: -1 for no attributionj, just a quote that can't be found on the net. We need a link or a genuine attribution. Or is this a transcription of a video or live talk you attended?

Comment: This is a transcription of a meeting of some members of an automotive company. I have to translate it and I can't ask the person who wrote that, only the person who has contacted me, and he can't clear anything. I can't provide any source or link because it does not exist. I know this is a difficult question, but I wanted to know the point of view of native English speakers. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @MariaSanchez I would take a guess at "books" (or "booths" if you prefer that) and use that in the translation. But when you send the translation back, include a note that you had to guess what was meant. The alternative would be to leave it out (and again note that you did that). I suspect you are going to have several similar problems given the poor quality of the English! Good luck.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Not a native speaker, or maybe just someone who works in marketing! "Group" may be capitalised because it is short for a proper noun (eg "the VW Group") and "trainings" may be shorthand/jargon for "trying sessions". It sounds like transcribed speech, so you would expect some informality and language errors. Presumably "boots" was a transcription error, rather than a production error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the word *boot* in the quote is nothing but a simple misspelling of [**booth**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/booth):

> A booth is a small area separated from a larger public area by screens or thin walls where, for example, people can make a phone call or vote in private.

Another word for the booths in the quote may be *cubicles*.

Comment: Plausible. There isn't really any way of deciding between this and **boot** (or something else completely).

Comment: or ot could be a misspelling of *bots* or who knows hwhat

Comment: @user The difference being that _booths_ fits semantically in the given sentence and context, whereas _bots_, or _who knows hwhat_(?) does not.

Comment: Are we talking about 'cubicles' here, maybe?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, that's another word for them.

Answer (score 1):

After some cursory research, I did find a word that might be applicable, though it is quite a stretch.

According to [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/boot), the word boot is a term in botany, which means:

> **a sheath enclosing the inflorescence**

This is supported by [Wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/boot#Noun), which defines the word as:

> **The inflated flag leaf sheath of a wheat plant.**

The quote states:

> we’re doing tests in plants

If the interpretation of the word **plants** is to be taken literally, as in a noun that denotes a type of living organism, then the entire sentence makes a bit more sense.

But here's the thing: nowhere in the quote did it mention anything botany in theme, or even anything else regarding plants. Additionally, the aforementioned meaning of **boot** is one that belongs to specialized teaching materials, scientific papers or highly technical lectures, not ramblings about training methods. This further supports my belief that the word was simply a mistake - one that either originates from a translation error or a gross misunderstanding of the word. So take this answer with a grain of salt.

Comment: Kudos for imaginative thinking, but no upvote. Sorry. :)

Comment: Understandable, considering the fact that it's too obscure of a word to be used in such a quote. I don't think this question can be answered definitively, at all. The only person who knows the answer is the one directly responsible for the quote, and no one else. I'd suggest putting this question on hold.

Comment: +1 for the attempt; it's better than writing a spurious answer as a joke, which passed through my mind

Comment: I'm not sure that there is a botanical context. I read 'plants' as meaning  industrial installations. This sounds very likely for specialised in-house training in a large organisation.

Answer (score -1):

Another possibility is that this isn't a typo for a word other than **boots** but a shortening of the phrase **boots on the ground**.

From [Grammarist](http://grammarist.com/idiom/boots-on-the-ground/):

> *Boots on the ground* refers to active ground troops in a military campaign, men or women who are physically present and fighting in a war zone.

In other words, the passage could be indicating that there are knowledgeable people on the floor (trainers with "boots on the ground") along with computers, both of which can be used to help with instruction and in-house testing.

But whatever it's intention really is, the writing is unclear.

Comment: "knowledgeable people on the floor (trainers with "boots on the ground") " - floorwalkers we call these in the UK. I recently found myself showing one how to do his job when we went to Windows 10 at work.